# Meta query key with POST OBJECT (ACF) (post_title) in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, meta-query

I have big problem with my meta query. I would like to filter my posts, and I need query to compare post_title with my $_POST value.
Code:

```
function postsFilter(){
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'posts',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND'
    )
);

if( isset($_POST['year']) && $_POST['year'] ) 
$args['meta_query'][] = array(
    'key' => 'year',
    'value' => $_POST['year'],
    'compare' => '='
);
if( isset($_POST['theme']) && $_POST['theme'] ) 
$args['meta_query'][] = array(
    'key' => 'theme',
    'value' => $_POST['theme'],
    'compare' => '='
);

if( isset($_POST['member']) && $_POST['member'] ) 
$args['meta_query'][] = array(
    'key' => 'member_relation',
    'value' => ``.$_POST['member'].``,
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
);


$query = new WP_Query( $args );

echo "<script>
var posts_p = '" . json_encode( $query->query_vars ) . "',
     current_page_p = " . 1 . " ,
     max_page_p = " . $query->max_num_pages . ";
     console.log(current_page_p, max_page_p);
</script>";

if( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
        get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'posts');
    endwhile;
    if (  $query->max_num_pages > 1 )
        echo '<div class="button-load-more_p btn-load-more text-center mx-auto w-100"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-md btn-with-icon fade-in full-visible load-more"><span>Load more</span></div></a></div>';
    wp_reset_postdata();
else :
    echo 'No publications found';
endif;

die();
```

}

and problem exists here:

```
if( isset($_POST['member']) && $_POST['member'] ) 
$args['meta_query'][] = array(
    'key' => 'member_relation',
    'value' => $_POST['member']
    'compare' => 'LIKE'
);
```

because I don't know how to write this part of query,
member relation is POST OBJECT type file in Wordpress, I need compare $_POST['member'] with post_title value (maybe I am wrong ?)

```
$member = get_field('member_relation', $post_object->ID); 
$member->post_title;
```

Is it possible to write this query? Please give me any advice or example solution of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try This, merge your meta query argument with the post title arg.

```
if( isset( $_POST['title'] ) && !empty( $_POST['title'] )  ){
                    
                        $args2 =  array( 
                                    's' => '"'.$_POST['title'].'"'
                                    ) ; 
                                    
                        $args = array_merge(  $args, $args2); 
                }
```